# Notify all goroutines

Tags: concurrency, tcp, parallel-processing, go

I am working on a TCP Server in Go. Now I want to notify all goroutines that are talking to clients to drop their connections, dump what they've got and stop.

Closing a channel is a way to notify all of them.

Question is: Is that idiomatic Go? If I am wrong; then what should I do (for notifying all of goroutines - something like ManualResetEvent in .NET)?

Note: I am a Go newbie, just learning and started with TCP Server because I have written that before in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, closing a channel is an idiomatic Go way of communicating between Goroutines.

You'll need to pass a channel into each goroutine as it launches and check the channel with the select call after each network event.

You'll also want to set timeouts on network events so that you don't have connections hanging around forever.

Comment: Thanks; I have a timeout for each connection as you said. But just for learning purpose: Is there another way to communicate with a mass of goroutines? (Other than a handmade mechanism)

Comment: How would the goroutine handle your communication if you don't specifically write code to handle that communication?

Comment: No; I meant some Go structures like channels or some Go tricks like embedding Mutex in the data structure. For example is it possible to embed a channel (not define a field) in my data structure so it can work with <- operator (I know that's not possible but just as an example). Thanks;

Answer (score 2):

As of Go 1.7, you can use the [context](https://blog.golang.org/context) package.